# Angular module not available with Gulp Babel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am getting the following error in my Angular app after adding `gulp babel` to my gulp file. I need this to transpile and minify my ES6:

> Cannot set property '0' of undefined

I'm thinking angular-file-saver doesn't like to babelfication.

Causing these errors:

> angular.js:33 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available!

[image]

Yet I can see the module being loaded client side:

[image]

**Gulp Task:** Note: this error only started occuring when I started piping through `babel`. If I remove `babelminify`, it produces the same error.

```
gulp.task('scripts-dev', () => {
  return gulp.src(paths.vendorJavascript.concat(paths.appJavascript, paths.appTemplates))
    .pipe(plugins.if(/html$/, buildTemplates()))
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: [['es2015', {modules: false}]]
    }))
    //.pipe(babelminify())
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmpJavascript))
    .pipe(plugins.connect.reload());
});
```

**This error occurs even without minifying taking place**

Comment: Any comments or help on this?

Comment: you can add `ng-strict-di` to your `ng-app` element in the HTML to have angular generate errors relating to any code that is not minification safe.  Beyond that, it's possible something isn't right with your gulp task that is causing some of your scripts to not be included....

Comment: @Claies see above, I added a picture (red text). I'm thinking angular-file-saver doesn't like to babelfication.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

using

```
.pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
//.pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))  gulp-ugligy is used
```

should serve your purpose